# Does Ubuntu support engineering software applications?

Tags: software-installation, compatibility

Does Ubuntu support engineering software like ETABS, SAP2000, Staad Pro, Autocad, Microstation etc?

Can I use a free version or cracked version of these applications?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the software you are looking to use should indicate what operating systems they support.  Many do not support Linux.  That leaves 2 options.  One is to find a free Linux alternative that does what you want.  The other is to run the Windows version of the software through Wine.  Whether the software runs properly, you can check Wine's website to verify this.  For instance Autocad is reported to work fairly well: [Autocad Support.](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=86)  For things not listed on their website, you would have to experiment and see what happens.